# Left Rotation using Java

Tags: java

Here I am Getting an ERROR

**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method leftRotatebyOne(int[], int) from the type LeftRotation**

Here is my code..

```
public static int[] arrayLeftRotation(int[] arr, int n, int k) 
{
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    leftRotatebyOne(arr, n); 
}

void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n) 
{
    int i, temp;
    temp = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i] = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++)
    {
        a[a_i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    int[] output = new int[n];
    output = arrayLeftRotation(a, n, k);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        System.out.print(output[i] + " ");
}
```

Can anybody tell to proceed me further.

Comment: Change `void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n) ` to `static void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n) `

Comment: Next time please include the stacktrace or at least some part of it. Here it was easy to deduce what the problem was, but usually it is not, so people would ask you for a complete error anyway. :)

Comment: I have tried, it affects the arrayLeftRotation(int[] arr, int n, int k) method to make return a result of type int[]

Comment: @SorapalliVenkatesh you need to return the array, as you have specified the return type to be `int[]` for `arrayLeftRotation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main method you are calling `arrayLeftRotation` method (which is static) which in turn is calling `leftRotatebyOne`, here `leftRotatebyOne` is non-static method, which is being called through a static method which is not allowed in java.

Change the declaration of the method `leftRotatebyOne` to static as follows

`static void leftRotatebyOne(int arr[], int n)`